# Can't seem to get proper coverage for Trigger

Tags: code-coverage

So.. I'm having a really hard time getting the trigger below to get coverage. I think I just don't know how to get coverage on the queries below. I create Test Data, but I'm stumped on how to get Part of the code even tested. Any Help would be greatly appreciated

```
trigger UpdateContactVerification on Lead (before insert, before update) {

    List<String> leadLinkedContact = new List<String>();
    Map<String, Contact > MVMap = new  Map<String, Contact >();

//Looks for Match in Contact where Lead Verification__c = Contact Verification__c and holds the Drupal ID and Email of the Lead to be used     below. 
    for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
        leadLinkedContact.add(lead.Verification__c);


    }
    for(Contact member :[SELECT Id,  Verification__c, Contact_Record_Type_Text__c, Drupal_ID__c, Email FROM Contact 
                                    WHERE (Contact_Record_Type_Text__c = 'Member') and (Verification__c IN :leadLinkedContact)]

       ){
       MVmap.put(member.Verification__c , member);
       MVmap.put(member.Email, member);
       MVmap.put(member.Drupal_ID__c, member);

    }
    for(Lead leadObj:Trigger.new){
        if(MVmap.ContainsKey(leadObj.Verification__c)){

                      leadObj.LinkedContact__c = MVmap.get(leadObj.Verification__c).id;   
                      leadObj.status = 'Closed - Duplicate'; 
                      MVmap.get(leadObj.Verification__c).email = leadObj.email;
                      MVmap.get(leadObj.Verification__c).Drupal_ID__c = leadObj.Drupal_ID__c;
                      update MVmap.get(leadObj.Verification__c);


    }
```

Here is the test class I created:

```
@istest

 public class LeadContactVerificationTest {


Static testMethod void LeadUpdateVerificationTestClass() {
//Test Against E-mail Address
Lead l1 = New Lead();
l1.FirstName = 'TestOne';
l1.LastName = 'Testing';
l1.Company = 'Individual';
l1.Email = 'testone@testing.com';
l1.Corps_Year__c = '2014';
l1.CorpsRegionnew__c = 'a05L00000015iZO';
l1.Drupal_ID__c = '12345';
insert l1;

Contact C1 = New Contact();
C1.FirstName = 'Testone';
C1.Lastname = 'Testing';
C1.Drupal_ID__c = '12345';
C1.Email = 'testone@testing.com';
insert C1;
}
}
```

Comment: don't forget your asserts in the test class - just getting code coverage alone is not best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
l1.Verification__c = 'test';
```

and

```
C1.Verification__c = 'test';
C1.Contact_Record_Type_Text__c = 'Member';
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I had tried the verification one before. But that field is actually a formula. So that might make a difference. But I think having the Contact_Record Type may be a big key to this.

I'll check it out. But I absolutely appreciate your help.

Comment: and I apologize. I should have included that information.

Comment: If it's a formula then set the referenced fields to their corresponding values so that the formula evaluates the same on the lead and the contact records.

Comment: So I had missed one on that... but it didn't help. 

So the parts of the code that are missing coverage are:
           ){
           MVmap.put(member.Verification__c , member);
           MVmap.put(member.Email, member);
           MVmap.put(member.Drupal_ID__c, member);

Comment: and 
       
                            leadObj.LinkedContact__c = MVmap.get(leadObj.Verification__c).id;   
                 leadObj.status = 'Closed - Duplicate'; 
                    MVmap.get(leadObj.Verification__c).Email = leadObj.Email;
                 MVmap.get(leadObj.Verification__c).Drupal_ID__c    = leadObj.Drupal_ID__c;
            
                    update MVmap.get(leadObj.Verification__c);

Comment: So basically I can't seem to get it to do something with the mapping. 
I'm currently going through a test case that was for something else that is giving it 70 percent coverage and seeing if I can figure out where I could tweak that one..

But It'd be nice to know what I"m doing wrong here too. 
(Again my thanks to you for your time)

Comment: So.. I rewrote the test as below and it is giving me 100 percent coverage. I'm not quite sure if I understand the difference. But I'm happy.

Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @istest

public class LeadContactVerificationTest {

    
Static testMethod void LeadUpdateVerificationTestClass() {
       // set up Contact
        Contact C1 = new Contact();
        C1.FirstName = 'TestOne';
  C1.LastName = 'Testing';
  C1.Drupal_ID__c = 'US';
        C1.Email = 'testone@testing.com';
  C1.Corp_Region__c = 'a05L00000015iZO';
  C1.Corps_Year__c = '2014';
        insert C1;

Comment: // set up leads
        List<Lead> testLeads = new List<Lead>();
        Lead lead1 = new Lead();
        lead1.Company = 'Individual';
        lead1.FirstName = 'TestOne'; 
  lead1.LastName = 'Testing';
  lead1.Email = 'testone@testing.com';
        lead1.Corps_Year__c = '2014';
  lead1.CorpsRegionnew__c = 'a05L00000015iZO';
  lead1.Drupal_ID__c = '12345';
        testLeads.add(lead1);

Comment: Lead lead2 = new Lead();
        lead2.Company = 'Individual';
        lead2.FirstName = 'TestOne'; 
  lead2.LastName = 'Testing';
  lead2.Email = 'testone2@testing.com';
        lead2.Corps_Year__c = '2014';
  lead2.CorpsRegionnew__c = 'a05L00000015iZO';
  lead2.Drupal_ID__c = '123456';
        testLeads.add(lead2);

Comment: Lead lead3 = new Lead();
        lead3.Company = 'Individual';
        lead3.FirstName = 'TestTwo'; 
  lead3.LastName = 'Testing';
  lead3.Email = 'test2@testing.com';
        lead3.Corps_Year__c = '2014';
  lead3.CorpsRegionnew__c = 'a05L00000015iZO';
  lead3.Drupal_ID__c = '1234556';
        testLeads.add(lead3); 
        
        insert testLeads;
  }
}

Comment: I marked yours as the right answer, as it set me down the right path. Thank you so much.